# Do you know what are the best Domain Specific Languages(DSL) tools for .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, dsl-tools

I would like to know what are the best DSL tools created to be used in .NET.? I have googled a bit, but, as I have no experience, I just want to be sure that the one I'm going to use is the best or it is among the best ones. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it you will be doing with the DSL tools? Specifying that would probably help

Comment: What if I answer "No I don't" (or "Yes I do")? I think the title shouldn't ask "if I know". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on MSDN, maybe it helps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126259.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The DynamicLanguageRuntime is your friend. Check out http://dlr.codeplex.com/